# GWT Unit Test Problem

Tags: java, gwt

I met a problem when I do GWT unit test.My GWT unit test can only succeed when my laptop disconnected from network, otherwise I receive the following error:

Starting http://192.168.1.103:65517/com.example.TestWebApp.JUnit/junit.html?gwt.codesvr=192.168.1.103:65513 on browser FF3
logging for HtmlUnit thread
   [ERROR] I/O error on HTTP request
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.103:65517 refused

Please help, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that when you're connected to the network, `localhost` is resolving to 192.168.1.103, and your servlet container is bound only to 127.0.0.1

When you're not connected to the net, `localhost` resolves to 127.0.0.1 and everything works fine.

Comment: You'd need to edit your question and post more details. Without knowing what your environment is and how you're connecting in your code, I can't really wager a guess. Ideally you either need to explicitly connect to 127.0.0.1 or have the servlet container bind to all interfaces.

Comment: You can either bind to all interfaces using 0.0.0.0, but more than likely, you need to edit /etc/hosts to point localhost to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, worked when I disabled network or by changing my hostname to something else than localhost